# Help understanding and fixing shut off valve

Tags: leak, valve, washing-machine, shutoff, identify-a-tool

I recently moved to a new house and am in the process of setting up essential appliances. While trying to connect the washing machine, I noticed that the shut off valve is leaking from a white hole(?) underneath. I want to know what the hole exactly is and how I can fix the leakage from it. See attached picture(side view and bottom view) for reference. Thanks in advance :)

Edit: I am from the Netherlands.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your general location/country might matter.  Off hand it might a vacuum breaker(prone to leaking) to prevent water being sucked back into the line.  Your local hardware/plumbing store should know about it and have the repairs parts.

Comment: To compound guessing with more guessing: If @crip659 is right, the problem might be scale in the valve, and who knows, maybe you can take it apart and clean it?   If so all you need to do is scratch off the scale with your fingernail.   Also the valve is attached with a compression nut so VERY easy to replace with a new one,

Answer (score 3):

That part prevents backflow into the water line.

It has flats so it can be unscrewed.

Purchase a replacement where you normally buy hardware or plumbing parts. (take the pics you posted here with you).

Unscrew the old part. Screw on the new, per instructions.  Done.